# Where can I change the nozzle diameter in Cura? Why is mine missing?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, nozzle

I just upgraded the nozzle (to 1 mm) on an Ender 3v2 and want to make a test print.  I added a new printer for the new nozzle size.... and can't find a setting for it.  Some screenshots on the internet show a nozzle diameter setting in the machine settings, but I do not have that. (**Manage printers** > **Printers** > **Machine Settings** > **Extruder 1**).  Obviously, this was the first place I looked, and I also looked in the sidebar several times.

I have Cura 4.11.0 and am using the Ender 3 profile.

I've seen arguments about it's no longer a valid setting because line width is more important, I've seen discussions that you need to install some mods to get to that variable, and I've seen people say to make a custom printer and then you can change the nozzle diameter.  I've also seen lots of people asking for help, and sometimes even posting "Oh I found it" later, but no details on where the setting is, why it's missing, etc.

https://old.reddit.com/r/ender3/comments/bw5d43/nozzle_diameter_settings_in_cura_40_missing/

https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/21438-suggestion-easy-change-nozzle-size/

Comment: Consider moving to a more competent / modern slicer.

Also, yes, nozzle diameter is irrelevant, only line width matters.

Comment: @towe Please clarify what is not competent/modern about Cura (e.g. they release updates very often) and which slicer do you think is better and why? As the comment stands now it could be considered inflammatory, it is an opinion. Personally, I've used and am using different slicers for different machines, my opinion, is that I do not think that Cura is not modern or not competent. :-) It is however sometimes difficult to understand the settings and the material profiles, so in that respect I can imagine there is room for improvement! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> Where can I change the nozzle diameter in Cura?

The best way forward is to go back to the Creality Ender 3 print profile, if so, you can use [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/19401/). So, you can select the correct nozzle size instantly.

[image: Ender 3 profile nozzle selection]

> Why is mine missing?

But, if you created a new printer profile, that option is not available. This is because that option is not available in custom print profiles. In order to use that option, the printer profile requires a variants configuration option; e.g. `"variants_name": "Nozzle Size"` for the Ender 3 profile and for Ultimaker printers that is `"variants_name": "Print core"` as they use a printer nozzle core concept. In order to use "variants", the printer profile needs to be aware that variants are available (from the Cura wiki as linked below):

> ```
>    # Whether your machine has the possibility to choose different variants.
>    # If this is set to "true", you will see the variant selection menu in Cura for your machine.
>    # By variants, we meant nozzles. You can have some specific variant profiles defined in folder
>    # "resources/variants". See files there as examples.
>    "has_variants": true,
> ```

*For more information on generating custom Cura printer profiles look into [Cura wiki "Definition File Types and the Base Definition Files"](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Definition-Files-Explained) and [Cura wiki "Adding new machine profiles to Cura"](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Adding-new-machine-profiles-to-Cura).*

So if you're profile doesn't support variants we need to revisit:

> Where can I change the nozzle diameter in Cura?

The nozzle diameter is part of the printer configuration, but, linked to the **Line Width** property. You therefor can set the line width to 1 mm to achieve the same. With respect to the nozzle diameter, it is also found for the custom printer layout using the following: with reference to version 4.13.0, the nozzle diameter is set in the machine setup. From the main menu go to **Settings**->**Printer**->**Manage Printers...**. Now select your printer (and activate it to be able to) select **Machine Settings** and go to the extruder tab sheet to change the nozzle diameter (option **Nozzle size** under nozzle settings).

[image: Cura printer preferences window]

[image: Printer settings]

[image: Extruder settings]

If you change the setting of the nozzle size you will see that this updates the option "**Line Width**" of the *Quality* group print settings to the same size. E.g. after changing the 0.4 mm nozzle value to 0.6 mm you will find the line width value updated:

[image: Updated line width property]

Answer (score 2):

This is for Cura 4.13.1 but it shouldn't be very different than 4.11.0. This is also for the standard Ender 3 profile; it is not necessary to create a new profile for a different nozzle.

In the main window, select your filament then a drop-down window will appear with the **Material** and **Nozzle Size**. Select **Nozzle Size** and pick the desired size from the drop-down menu.

Comment: This is valid for the Ender 3 profile, but when you have created a new printer, the nozzle size option is not available! (This is buried in the printer settings...) Basically, this answer is valid for the Ender 3 profile, not for a custom profile as the OP questioned. So, either redirect the OP back to the Ender 3 profile or add a section to cover custom FDM printer settings. I've linked my answer to your answer explaining it is valid for an Ender 3 profile, you might want to do that in your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

To confirm the OP's issue using Cura 5.2.1 and 5.3 (4/13/2023), as opposed to 4.x, I am attempting to change nozzle size on Ender 3 Pro and this is not in the following menu:

`Manage Printers>Ender 3 Pro>Machine Settings>Extruder`

You can see on the left, I am using Cura version 5.2.1 (Mac OS 12.6 Monterrey)

[image: Cura version]

I was trying to create a profile for when I have the 1 mm Nozzle on there:

[image: Preferences - Profiles dialog]

I *was* able to find Nozzle Diameter in a different place and change it successfully:

[image: Nozzle diameter location]

Comment: Please clarify your "Answer" because it almost sounds like you are having the same problem as the OP and are searching for a solution.

Comment: I have added a diagram with the solution - it shows that it is in a different location

Comment: How is this different than other posted answers (other than your diagram)?

Comment: My data is for Cura 5.3 and seems slightly different than other answers.